# What UIKit classes respond usefully to sizeThatFits?

Tags: ios, uikit

Is there a list *anywhere* of the UIKit classes that respond meaningfully to `-(CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size` (and, by extension, `-(void)sizeToFit`)?

The UIView docs mention UISwitch and UIImageView. I know UILabel does, but I don't see it documented anywhere.

Trial and error and pray Apple doesn't change their mind? Seems insane.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask this question the other way. What view are you having trouble resizing?

Comment: I could, but that would be a different question. To your point, I almost did ask a question about UITextField but figured it out via trial and error. (Yes, UITextField does do something sensical for sizeThatFits, but it uses the greater of the text length and the placeholder length, regardless of which is showing.) But since I haven't found this documented, in theory it could change. Or maybe it is documented somewhere and I just haven't found it ... even after a lot of time consuming looking. I'm trying to avoid wasting that time for every class I think about calling sizeThatFits on.